# Why can't I update this foreign key property?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have two classes, here are the relevant bits:

```
public class Endorsement
{
    public Guid? ContractId { get; set; }
    public virtual Contract Contract { get; set; }
}

public class Contract
{
     public virtual ICollection<Endorsement> Sales { get; set; }
}
```

The `Endorsement` class doesn't have a corresponding configuration, but the `Contract` class does:

```
public class ContractConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Contract>
{
    public ContractConfiguration()
    {
         HasMany(a => a.Sales).WithRequired(a => a.Contract).HasForeignKey(a => a.ContractId);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to change the `Contract` on an `Endorsement` to another `Contract`:

```
var endorsement = Context.Set<Endorsement>().Find(endorsementId);
var newContract = Context.Set<Contract>().Find(newContractId);
endorsement.Contract = newContract;
/* Instead of the line above, I have also tried endorsement.ContractId = newContract.Id;
   I have also tried newContract.Sales.Add(endorsement); and then setting the state of 
   the newContract entry to modified and saving, all with the same results.
*/

var entry = Context.Entry(endorsement);
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
Context.SaveChanges();
```

`Context.SaveChanges();` throws the following exception:

> The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'Contract.Id' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'Endorsement.ContractId' on the other end.

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: I don't think you need those two statements :var entry = Context.Entry(endorsement);
entry.State = EntityState.Modified, assignment itself should be enough.

Comment: @J.W. I removed those calls. That eliminated the exception but now the record isn't getting updated in the database.

Comment: I found why the db wasn't getting updated after removing those calls, we're setting `Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` in the context ctor. We are setting `Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;` however, and the `Endorsement` class meets all the requirements listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx) for creating POCO proxies.

Comment: Doing a little more debugging I can see that the `endorsement` object is a dynamic proxy, however before setting the `entry.Sate = EntityState.Modified;` the `entry.State` is Unchanged.

Comment: Why do you have `AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false`? You should only do this when it's absolutely necessary and when you know the consequences.

Comment: Couldn't tell you, this is a legacy system I'm inheriting. My guess is they ran in to performance issues and did that instead of fixing it correctly. I'll find out more tomorrow. Meantime, putting a call to `Context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` before `Context.SaveChanges()` fixed the issue I was having in my original question.

Comment: Thanks Mike B, `Context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` did the trick for me too. I wish I knew why, but you can't have everything I suppose...